# DataFrame write 10x slower than RDD save to cassandra in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I tried comparing cassandra save for a table with 30,000 records for RDD and DataSet. I found that Dataset save was 10 times slower compared to RDD.
The table has 4 partitioning keys.

```
 DSE Version :5.1.7
 Spark version :2.0.1
 Nodes:6( 20 cores each 6g)
 Using Spark Standalone
```

We used the following spark configurations:

1. spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size=100000
2. spark.locality.wait=1
3. spark.dse.continuous_paging_enabled=false
4. spark.cassandra.input.fetch.size_in_rows=500
5. spark.cassandra.connection.keep_alive_ms=10000
6. spark.cassandra.output.concurrent.writes=2000
7. num-cpu-cores=48
8. memory-per-node=3g
9. spark.executor.cores=3
10. spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls=true
11. spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec=10
12. spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
13. spark.cassandra.connection.local_dc=dc1
14. spark.cassandra.connection.compression=LZ4
15. spark.cassandra.connection.connections_per_executor_max=20

Following is the sample code for the same:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

import sparkSession.implicits._

val RDD1 = sc.cassandraTable[TableName]("keySpace1", "TableName")
           .where("id =?,id)

RDD1.saveToCassandra("keySpace1", "TableName")

var DS1 = sparkSession.read
           .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
           .options(Map("table" -> "TableName", "keyspace" ->"keySpace1"))
           .load()
           .where("id ='"+ id +"'").as[CaseClassModel]

DS1.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")          
  .mode(SaveMode.Append).option("table", "TableName1")                
  .option("keyspace", "KeySpace1")
  .save()
```

Answer (score 4):

Since both Dataframe and RDD methods use the same underlying save code it is unlikely that you would see such a drastic difference unless the overhead of the conversion into DF types was very very high. In our own tests over billions of rows we see only a few percent difference in speed.

While 30k records is a very small amount and any amount of overhead could become relevant, I think the most likely cause would be the lookup in the where clause being interpreted differently in the RDD and DF code. I would check to make sure it is correctly being pushed in the DF code (see the `explain` for the DF load.)

Comment: We actually used the exact same where clause for both Rdd and dataset,even then we get the same difference

Comment: As i was trying to let you know, the Where clause in the DF implementation is actually different. Even if it has *literally* the same text. Dataframes will convert the predicate into a DF class and check if types match correctly. If they don't it could fall back to doing a full scan instead of a predicate pushdown. This is why I said you should run the *explain* command to see exactly what is happening in the DF code.